# Error in using subquery in access join query

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, alias

I need to use the result of a query as a lookup field for another query.  What I tried was using a sub query aliased as something, but finally I got some error saying "enter parameter value" for `variz.variz` and `Y.varizname`.

I've searched in forums, but I can't find any similar problem.

```
SELECT sahmeharkas.attrib, 
    [sahmeharkas]![expenseper] AS Expense,
    variz.variz
FROM sahmeharkas
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT variz.varizname FROM variz GROUP BY variz.varizname) as Y
ON sahmeharkas.attrib =  Y.variz.varizname
```

Comment: What SQL flavor are you using?

Comment: @alexgrounds  I use Microsoft Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table `variz` does not exist outside of the subquery; you should instead use the subquery alias as the table qualifier, e.g.:

```
select s.attrib, s.expenseper as expense, y.variz
from 
    sahmeharkas s left join 
    (select v.variz, v.varizname from variz v group by v.variz, v.varizname) y on
    s.attrib = y.varizname
```

Comment: thank u. i made your suggested changes.but the problem stands yet.i did it : `code SELECT sahmeharkas.attrib,
 -[sahmeharkas]![expenseper] AS مانده,
Y.variz
FROM sahmeharkas LEFT JOIN (SELECT variz.varizname AS namee FROM variz GROUP BY variz.varizname)  AS Y ON sahmeharkas.attrib =  Y.varizname`

Comment: You are not following my example: your subquery does not output the `variz` field, and you have assigned a new alias (`namee`) to `varizname` which you will need to reference in the outer query (i.e. changing `y.varizname` to `y.namee`).

Comment: Wow Great!!! it works as it should! it solved my old problem.thank u . i will learn a lot from it.thank u thank u

Comment: just another question.In design view there has been added a table with my Alias.indeed it is a imaginary table. how i can i create this without using SQL?

Comment: You're welcome; to avoid the 'imaginary' table in design view, save the subquery SQL `select v.variz, v.varizname from variz v group by v.variz, v.varizname` as a separate saved query called `y`, and then simply reference the query `y` in your main query.